# Expression for Euler characteristic in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

Is the Euler-Poincare$ ^{\prime}$ characteristic $\chi$ a bending invariant? If so, how should it be isometrically expressed in terms of first fundamental form coefficients?

Is not *stretching invariant* better as terminology? If so how can it be expressed in terms of the first and second form coefficients ?  and/or in any other way?

[$\chi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euler characteristic in a homotopy invariant, and that is a more precise  statement that the one you want.

The Gauss-Bonnet theorem states that the Euler characteristic of a closed orientable surface is equal, up to normalization, to the integral of the gaussian curvature.

More generally the Chern-Gauss-Bonnet theorem does the same thing for closed orientable manifolds of even dimension. Now you do not integrate the curvature but something derived from it. (The Euler characteristic of closed odd-dimensional manifoldsis zero, so nothing inteeresting can be said there)

This is very well explained in Spivak's book on differential geometry.

Comment: Homotopy combines differential bending and dilatation, correct? And so in Wiki it should be more precisely termed as a homotopy invariant?

Comment: Homotopy is much more general than that. I suggeest you read the page on homotopy in WIkipedia or, much better, in Munkres' book, for example.